# How do I fill ONE View from Separate Tables using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have tables: Teachers and Students.

We have a SpecialProjects Table where Teachers and Students are assigned to work in a Project Together

```
SpecProjID, SpecProjName, isTeacher , teacherID , isStudent, studentID
```

we have to fill View for each Special Project with values : FirstName , LastName , Email. ToList()

We need to grab the info from the two separate tables with logic like:

```
If isTeacher then get FirstName from Teacher table

If isStudent then get FirstName from Student table
```

and fill the View.ToList()

How do I fill ONE View from Separate Tables using Linq?

Comment: A `Join` with a `Select` maybe?

Comment: This might be useful: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var view = Teachers.Select( 
              t => new { t.FirstName, t.LastName, t.Email } ).
           Union( Students.Select( 
              t => new { t.FirstName, t.LastName, t.Email }) ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Phil thanks and it worked .. I was able to get the entire code working with your help. The Union is slick :)

```
var rosterTeacher = ctx.SpecialProject
    .Where(sp => sp.caseID == cID && sp.isTeacher)
    .Join(ctx.Teachers, m => m.teacherID, p => p.teacherID,
          (sp, m) => new SpecProjRosterView
                        {
                            RosterEmail = m.memEMail,
                            RosterName = (m.memLastName + ", " + m.memFirstName),
                            RosterVerified = sp.caseRosterIsVerified
                        }).ToList();

var rosterStudents = ctx.SpecialProject
    .Where(c => c.caseID == cID && c.isStudents)
    .Join(ctx.CaseStudents, u => u.studentID, p => p.studentID,
          (sp, m) => new SpecProjRosterView
                        {
                            RosterEmail = m.caseStudentsEMail,
                            RosterName = (m.caseStudentsLastName + ", " + m.caseStudentsFirstName),
                            RosterVerified = sp.caseRosterIsVerified
                        }).ToList();

return rosterTeacher.Union(rosterStudents).ToList();
```